# Troubleshooting fan issue

Tags: 16.04, fan, temperature

I'm troubleshooting high-rpm fans on my Alienware Aurora R3. I need help understanding the fan2 ALARM and temp3 FAULT in the lm-sensors output below. The xsensors temp3 reading is at 262.4.

Motherboard base product name is 046MHW. I'm unclear if I've setup the configuration correctly for it.

```
lynn@lynn-Aurora-R3:~$ sensors -f
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +114.8°F  (crit = +248.0°F, hyst = +194.0°F)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +87.8°F  (high = +176.0°F, crit = +208.4°F)
Core 0:         +86.0°F  (high = +176.0°F, crit = +208.4°F)
Core 1:         +86.0°F  (high = +176.0°F, crit = +208.4°F)
Core 2:         +86.0°F  (high = +176.0°F, crit = +208.4°F)
Core 3:         +87.8°F  (high = +176.0°F, crit = +208.4°F)

f71889a-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:        +3.31 V  
in1:          +1.37 V  (max =  +2.04 V)
in2:          +1.15 V  
in3:          +0.87 V  
in4:          +0.70 V  
in5:          +1.43 V  
in6:          +1.67 V  
3VSB:         +3.31 V  
Vbat:         +3.33 V  
fan1:        4043 RPM
fan2:           0 RPM  ALARM
fan3:        3529 RPM
temp1:        +96.8°F  (high = +185.0°F, hyst = +177.8°F)
                       (crit = +212.0°F, hyst = +204.8°F)  sensor = transistor
temp2:        +91.4°F  (high = +185.0°F, hyst = +177.8°F)
                       (crit = +212.0°F, hyst = +204.8°F)  sensor = transistor
temp3:          FAULT  (high = +158.0°F, hyst = +154.4°F)
                       (crit = +185.0°F, hyst = +181.4°F)  sensor = transistor
```

How do I figure out what the specific issue is from the output for my motherboard?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, fan1 and fa3 are both running ~4000 rpm, and fan2 appears dead... but the fans aren't running because of overtemp CPUs at 86 degrees. I'd check your BIOS and make sure it's up to date and configured correctly, and check your sensors config file.